# How to make a table in a webpage scroll vertically while making everything else fixed in position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to scroll a particular table in my webpage scroll vertically with mouse scroll event, while keeing everything else including the background image fixed in position.

This is my css script for the table

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
            table{
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.7);
              text-align: center;
              font-family: opensans;
              font-size: 20px;
              color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 255);
              width: 70vw;
              height: 100px;
              overflow-y: scroll;
              overflow-x: hidden;
            }
          }
```

And this is the script for background and header

```
body{
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 255);
            background: url("background.jpg");
            background-position: 49% 20%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-blend-mode: luminosity;
          }

.Header{
            font-family: Neon;
            font-size: 40px;
            position: fixed;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 35px;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
          }
```

Unfortunately the header remains fixed in its position but the background of the page is not. I tried adding the background position fixed as follows

```
body{
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 255);
            background: url("background.jpg");
            background-position: fixed;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-blend-mode: luminosity;
          }
```

But still the background goes up(vertically scrolled) while scrolling.

Comment: The reason your `body` scrolls is because it's too big for the window.  Make the content less than the window and the body won't scroll.  Then make the content scrollable within itself.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the table in a div with `overflow-y: auto` and set the height of the `div` to, for example, `100px`

Answer (score -1):

add `background-attachment` to be fixed. 
check the below snippet

```
body {
    background-image: url("img_tree.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
   }
```

[1](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp): [background-attachment property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)